# Что даёт использование FOREIGN ключа

Tags: mysql

Какие преимущества даёт использование FOREIGN ключа в MySQL. Может скорость выборки из связанных таблиц, или что то другое?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конкретно MySQL тут ни при чем. Понятие внешних ключей есть не только в MySQL, но и в MS SQL и в Oracle и вообще в реляционных базах данных. Нужно это для обеспечения целостности данных. Что касается скорости, то они ее, скорее, несколько уменьшают - при вставке/обновлении надо следить за тем, что вставляемая/обновляемая запись содержит только те ключи, что определены в таблице, на которую этот ключ ссылается, при удалении - удалять записи, зависящие от данного ключа